# Django Admin Login --> Redirect on Login to another Page

Tags: django, django-admin

Good evening,

I am currently trying to solve a problem with Django Admin.

I want to do this steps:
1.) If I visit localhost:8000/admin --> the Admin Login appears
2.) If I log in with credentials --> it should redirect me to localhost:8000/test_page and not to the localhost:8000/admin page.
3.) If I revisit localhost:8000/admin while I am logged in, it should show me the admin page.

I was already looking in /python3.x/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py but couldn`t find the code piece to make 2.) and 3.) work.

Anyone got an idea or could help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You may refer to this link that proposes a workaround to resolve a similar case: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1259008

Comment: this only works if you want to redirect to admin pages :(, i want to redirect to another page on my site like localhost:8000/test_page

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a "solution".

In the file `contrib/admin/sites.py`, around line 368, there is the function:

```
def login(self, request, extra_context=None)
```

After:

```
if (REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME not in request.GET and
        REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME not in request.POST):
    context[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME] = reverse('admin:index', current_app=self.name)
```

I simply added this line:

```
context[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_page'
```

So it looks like this now:

```
if (REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME not in request.GET and
        REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME not in request.POST):
    context[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME] = reverse('admin:index', current_app=self.name)
context[REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_page'
```

Now, if you visit http://127.0.0.1/admin and you are not logged in, it will show you the login page. After logging in, it will redirect you to the `test_page`.

If you visit /admin again it will show you the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

1. Set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in you setting.py.
2. Set `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = ""` instead of `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = "next"` in  `django.contrib.auth`.